# LINQ WHERE based on comparison to other elements in the result set

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that looks very similar to the following:

```
var query = plans
.Where(p => 
        p.IsOptOut ||
        (p.PropertyType == PropertyType.Property1 && p.SomeCollection.Count > 0))
.Select(p =>
        new CustomClass
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            PropertyType = p.PropertyType,
            IsOptOut = p.IsOptOut
        });
```

So we select from `plans` any records where `IsOptOut` is true OR `p.PropertyType` is a specific value AND `p.SomeCollection` has at least one record.

This would lend itself to a possible result set like the following:

```
Id          PropertyType          IsOptOut
1           Foo                   true
2           Foo                   false
3           Foo                   false
4           Bar                   true
5           Baz                   true
6           Baz                   false
```

How can I modify the LINQ query such that the WHERE clause can compare the current record to the other records in the `plans` collection and exclude any records where IsOptOut is true AND it's the only record returned for the given property type.

In the example above, ID #4 should be excluded from the result set because IsOptOut is true and there are no other records in the result set for the PropertyType of "Bar".

As a side note, it's a business rule that if `IsOptOut` is true, there will be no records in `SomeCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly in the same `Where` clause, but can use something like this (see the comments):

```
var query = plans
.Where(p => 
        p.IsOptOut ||
        (p.PropertyType == PropertyType.Property1 && p.SomeCollection.Count > 0))
.GroupBy(p => p.PropertyType) // group the result by property type so we can count the items
.Where(g => !(g.Count() == 1 && g.FirstOrDefauilt().IsOptOut)) // apply the requested criteria
.SelectMany(g => g) // flatten back the result
.Select(p =>
        new CustomClass
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            PropertyType = p.PropertyType,
            IsOptOut = p.IsOptOut
        });
```